# Firebase database - react native - TLS session resumption

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a social chat app with react native, and have been struggling with choosing between firebase and hosting an AWS EC2 server.

I love using firebase and would prefer to use it for my app, however I'm worried about the pricing of the bandwidth. As the app is a chat application, there will be lots of opening and shutting down of the app, and small messages sent. It appears that the main problem with this would be the TLS session handshake required to interact with the db.

I've read the docs, and seen that certain devices don't use TLS session resumption which can incur large costs. I've honeslty not heard of this before and wonder whether theres anything I can do to combat the problem.

Is it possible to persist the connection to firebase servers so I don't have to keep initiating an SSL handshake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any control over the connection that the Firebase SDK maintains to the server.  In fact, the Firebase SDK itself doesn't have any control over the connection with regards to how the host OS manages the lifecycle of the browser or app.  If the host OS decides that the process should stop networking because it's no longer in the foreground (in order to save the user the cost of data transfer), then it will simply shut down its ability to network.  Also, the host OS may decide that the app's process is no longer needed because the user isn't looking at it any more.  So it may simply kill off that process.

Essentially, as an app developer, you are forced to work within the constraints imposed by the host OS, and these constraints are set in place for the benefit of the end user to save data and battery.

Comment: Thanks for replying Doug. I see, that makes things pretty simple for me. One question regarding this issue, In the documentation, under the Optimize Usage heading, it states that I should issue TLS session tickets. I'm using the web sdk in a react native application. Is this anything that I should be doing? Sorry for my ignorance, this is kind of new to me

Comment: Which page of documentation are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, Under the optimize usage heading here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing

Comment: That's not a choice you have - the user's device either supports it or it doesn't.  Most should.

Comment: then why is it listed on the documentation under, quote;
"There are a few best practices you can employ"
so, question is, how does one "Employ" this if you can?
else, like most advanced things in the documentation is false and missrepresentative

Comment: ultimately, the goal of TLS session is to reduce the 3.7kb SSL overhead, very helpful for lots of micro reads for data that is not sensative.
See another document reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize#ssl-sessions